# Identificador para formulario Ajax.BeginForm en asp.net mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un formulario para registro el cual quiero ponerle un id

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Registrar", new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                UpdateTargetId = "div_tabla_sucursal",
                OnSuccess = "Limpiar"
            },
            new { @id="frmRegistro" }))
            {
                <div id="div_formulario_registrar_sucursal">
                    @Html.Partial("_ListaFormularioRegistrarSucursal", Model.Modelo_Sucursales)
                </div>
            }
```

Pero cuando lo agregué me genera lo siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tambien tengo otro formulario el cual no me genera ese error

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Filtrar", "Usuario", null,
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        UpdateTargetId = "Div_Tabla_Usuarios",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
    }, new { @id = "frmFiltrarNombrePersona" }))
{
    @Html.Label("Ingrese el nombre de la persona")
    @Html.TextBox("NombrePersona", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
    <div id="Div_Tabla_Usuarios">
        @Html.Partial("_TablaUsuarios", Model)
    </div>
}
```

En ejemplos que he buscado me los presenta de la misma manera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando usa el overload de BeginForm con tres parametros (como hizo ud.), el tercér es un objecto de clase AjaxOptions y en su código es un String.  Las firmas pueden ser `(String, String, AjaxOptions)` o `(String, Object, AjaxOptions)` y suyo es `(String, AjaxOptions, String)` .  El ejemplo que puso tiene cuatro parametros, `(String, String, AjaxOptions, AjaxOptions)` (el tercér en el ejemplo es null.)

Comment: Para mi sobrecarga sería :"@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Registrar",new { @id="Frm_Registro" }, new AjaxOptions" para poder colocarle el id? he probado así pero no realiza la acción que definí en OnSuccess

Comment: Creo que sí, String (acción...lo que hace el controlador), Object (route values, en ese caso un objecto anonimo que contiene el Id), AjaxOptions.

Comment: Quedó de la siguiente manera ```@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Registrar","", new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                UpdateTargetId = "div_tabla_sucursal",
                OnSuccess = "Limpiar"
            }, new { @id = "Frm_Registro" }))```, así me funcionó, gracias por tu colaboración, super útil porque no había tomado en cuenta las sobrecargas.